# Are asking-for-resources questions considered as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Reading the FAQs, I found that asking-for-resources questions is not covered in the FAQs.

Can I ask asking-for-resources questions in the main site, such as:

1. Are there any resources that explain how to start making your first film?
2. Can you recommend books/sites that explain how movie is produced from the start until the distribution?
3. [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1375/is-there-a-good-resource-which-analyzes-many-parody-movies-for-what-is-being-la)

Are asking for resources such as those considered off-topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider 1 & 2 be off-topic not because they are bad questions, but because this site is more for Movie & TV enthusiasts.  However, I would venture a guess that specific questions would be on-topic for the [**Audio-Video Production**](https://video.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange Beta site.

As for the third point, it's kind of on a weird edge case.  The question is not a *bad* question per se; but it definitely comes close/is a *list* question due to there not being one right answer but the asker is asking for something *specific* and it has not received much attention at all so therefore, I don't know if closing it is the best thing for it.

Comment: Gotta agree with both you and Nobby on this question.  The edge case is interesting, as it *is* a list question - but not in the way as 'what movies are set in the wild-west?' would be - soliciting dozens of answers.  This question may never be answered as a resource may not be out there.

Answer (score 3):

I would agree with TylerShads here - none of these questions are really a good fit for MTV, even the last one has issues.

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like they would fit in Audio-Video Production either as that site seems more geared to the technicians and engineers rather than the directors/producers of film.

I am currently committed to the Filmmaking Site - but it appears to be dead in the water. You could head over there in Area 51 and see if you want to get involved with promoting it as it would be a good fit for the first two questions.

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8544/film-making

Comment: +1, didn't even realize that A51 existed.  Mayhaps if it is dead, ask AVP to accept filmmmaking questions as well?